# Is there a way to change the data by adjusting a trend line

Tags: excel, charts, trendline

I have a set of data charted and a trend line for the data (in Excel). Is there a way to change the slope of the trend line and it will adjust the data to match the new slope?

Comment: No. However, you can always take the equation for the trend line and calculate the data that comprise it, then create a new data set that adjusts for the slope of the trend line.

Comment: FYI, in Excel 97 to 2003, dragging data points would actually change the underlying data. That "feature" was eliminated in Excel 2007.

Comment: @chuff How do I get the equation of the trend line?

Comment: When you add the trend line to the chart, on the **Trendline Option** selection in the **Format Trendline** dialog box, there's a check mark box for **Display equation on chart**.

Comment: @chuff If you combine all your comments into an answer, I'm happy to mark it the answer (points for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. However, you can take the equation for the trend line and calculate the data that comprise it, then create a new data set that adjusts for the slope of the trend line that you want to use.

To get the equation - slope and offset - of the original trend line, select the trend line on the chart, right-click and choose **Format Trendline**. At the bottom of the dialog box that opens up, there is a check box for **Display equation on chart**. The equation will be put in a new text box on the chart, and you can copy the equation directly from the box.

Prior to Excel 2007, it was possible - by changing the position of a point on a chart - to change the underlying data as well. In response to user feedback, a **[free addin](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/11/02/excel-add-in-for-manipulating-points-on-charts-mpoc.aspx)** was developed to provide this kind of capability. I have not tried it, but perhaps you will find it helpful.